# What is the difference between '\n' or "\n" in C++?

Tags: c++, newline

I've seen the new line `\n` used 2 different ways in a few code examples I've been looking at. The first one being `'\n'` and the second being `"\n"`. What is the difference and why would you use the `'\n'`?

I understand the `'\n'` represents a char and `"\n"` represents a string but does this matter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`'\n'`is a character constant.

`"\n"` is a pointer to character array equivalent to `{'\n', '\0'}` (`\n` plus the null terminator)

**EDIT**

I realize i explained the difference, but didn't answer the question.

Which one you use depends on the context.  You use `'\n'` if you are calling a function that expects a character, and `"\n"`, if it expects a string.

Answer (score 9):

`'\n'` is a char literal. `"\n"` is a string literal (an array of chars, basically).

The difference doesn't matter if you're writing it to an ordinary stream. `std::cout << "\n";` has the same effect as `std::cout << '\n';`.

In almost every other context, the difference matters. A char is not in general interchangeable with an array of chars or with a string.

So for example `std::string` has a constructor which takes a `const char*`, but it doesn't have a constructor which takes a `char`. You can write `std::string("\n");`, but `std::string('\n');` doesn't compile.

`std::string` also has a constructor which takes a `char` and the number of times to duplicate it. It doesn't have one that takes a `const char*` and the number of times to duplicate it. So you can write `std::string(5,'\n')` and get a string consisting of 5 newline characters in a row. You can't write `std::string(5, "\n");`.

Any function or operation that you use will tell you whether it's defined for a char, for a C-style string, for both via overloading, or for neither.

Comment: typo! Forgot the slash in the second case: `std::cout << '\n';`.

Answer (score 2):

`'\n'` is a `char` constant.

`"\n"` is a `const char[2]`.

So usage is something like this:

```
char newLine = '\n';
const char* charPointerStringNewLine = "\n"; // implicit conversion
const char charStringNewLine[2] = "\n";

string stringNewLine( "\n" );
```

So in short: one is a pointer to a character array, the other is a single character.

Comment: `"\n"` is a `const char[2]`, not a `const char*`. The former is implicitly convertible to the latter, though.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes denote a character and double quotes denote a string. Depending on the context, you can choose which data type to work with.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the '\n' represents a char and "\n" represents a string but does this matter?

If you understand this, then it should be clear that it does indeed matter. Overloaded functions in the C++ standard library often hide this fact, so maybe an example from C will be more useful: `putchar` takes a single character, so only `'\n'` is correct, whereas `puts` and `printf` take a string, and in that case, only `"\n"` is correct.